# PhP shell execute ignores Exceptions

Tags: php, shell, exception, shell-exec

I have the strangest bug. I was like wtf^12.

I have a script wchich calls following function:

```
function checkNewFilename($newFilename)
{
    if (file_exists($newFilename)) {

        if (!unlink($newFilename)) {
            debugDeploy($newFilename . ' already exists and could not be deleted.');
            throw new Exception($newFilename . ' already exists and could not be deleted.');
        }
    }
}
```

It gets used like this:

```
$newFilename = $defaultConfig . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'client.xml'; 
checkNewFilename($newFilename);
echo 'wtf is happening here';
copy($configFilename, $newFilename);
```

Now when i run this code with normall browser/xdebug i get a cachable fatal error as it should  be. BUT when i run the script via shell on

```
php script.php param param param
```

Somthing nuts happens. IT ignores the exceptions and gous as nothing happend. I get the error before the exception AND the echo after the function call... wth.

I am runing on

> PHP 5.3.3-7+squeeze14 with Suhosin-Patch (cli) (built: Aug  6 2012
>   14:18:06) Copyright (c) 1997-2009 The PHP Group Zend Engine v2.3.0,
>   Copyright (c) 1998-2010 Zend Technologies
>       with Xdebug v2.2.5, Copyright (c) 2002-2014, by Derick Rethans
>       with Suhosin v0.9.32.1, Copyright (c) 2007-2010, by SektionEins GmbH

Anyone has any idea what causes this strange behavior?

Comment: Likely your command-line environment is different from your web environment. At the very least the process almost certainly a different user, which means different file system rights. It could also be that PHP is using a different configuration.

Comment: Ok. il start with easy ones... how do i change user ownerschip? :P